# How to access parent twig templates attributes property?

Tags: drupal, twig

I have **field.html.twig:**

```
{%- for item in items -%}
 <div{{ item.attributes }}>
  {{ item.content }} //Calls field-collection-item--field-banner.html.twig
  //I want to access {{item.content.title}} of child but I can't
 </div>
{%- endfor -%}
```

**field-collection-item--field-banner.html.twig**

```
{{content.title}}
//I want to access the attributes property of the parent template, but I can't
```

How can I either:

1. Access the parent attributes property from second template, Or
2. Access {{content.title}} from the first template?

Comment: Have you tried `{% extends "field.html.twig" %}` already?

Comment: I'm only seeing one template here, what do you mean with "calls field...twig"?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? because i think there is a better way to do this. You cannot access the attributes in field-collection-item--field-banner.html.twig. You can access the title (probably) like {{ item.content.title  }}. You can turn on twig debugging and do {{ dump(items) }} to see what is in the items array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to acces info. And if the item you called has an array inside it. you should define it something like:

`{{ item.content[1].title }}` <-- this wil give items out of array item one or two.

> "Access the parent attributes property from second template"

I do not really understand totally but you can try `{{ record.ITEM }}`.

If that doesnt work just try something like `{% SETCONTENT ITEMS = "contenttype" %}`
. Then you can dirty call uppon on the items in there.

But lets say you have an Blog and have more items and different contents but want to call upon it anyway. then **ONLY IF YOU USE CONTENT TYPES YML FILES** you would have to define the listing template and record template like this:

```
[CONTENTYPE]:
   name: [YOUR NAME]
   singular_name: [YOUR SINGULAR NAME]
listing_template: [LISTING.twig]
record_template: [RECORD.twig]
listing_records: [NUMBER OF SHOWN ITEMS]
```

I hope this wouldv helped somewhat. I have no idea if you have somewhat a content type file or something. But I work a lot with twig and this is how it would work in a CMS like Bolt or some other ones. But i gave some options that would be able to work so hope it helps.